# Finding and Replacing Duplicates With Correct Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with duplicate family IDs but different number of family members:

```
tbl_family

+------------+--------------+---------+
| familyID   | Members      | Location|
+------------+--------------+---------+
|      100   | 3            |    xyz  |
|      100   | 4            |    xyz  |
|      101   | 1            |    abc  |
|      101   | 2            |    abc  |
|      102   | 5            |    efg  |
|      103   |              |    hij  |
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

I also have a second table where we verified the correct count of family members for the duplicates

```
tbl_verifier

+------------+--------------+---------+
| familyID   | Members      | Location|
+------------+--------------+---------+
|      100   | 3            |    xyz  |
|      101   | 2            |    abc  |
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

I want to create a view in mysql which will display the families without duplicates and maintain the row with the verified count of family members. The results should look as follows:

```
tbl_results
+------------+--------------+---------+
| familyID   | Members      | Location|
+------------+--------------+---------+
|      100   | 3            |    xyz  |
|      101   | 2            |    abc  |
|      102   | 5            |    efg  |
|      103   |              |    hij  |
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

I am breaking the problem into several steps. I want to first select all those with matching Members then those with null Members

```
/* Step 1: Select only those that are matching family members count in 
verifier and family */

select *
from tbl_family f
inner join
tbl_verifier v
ON f.familyID = v.familyID
WHERE f.Members = v.Members;

/* Step 2 : Select only those that have null  number of rooms*/

select *
from tbl_family f
left join
tbl_verifier v
ON f.familyID = v.familyID
WHERE f.Members is null
```

Now am a bit stuck on how to proceed further.

Comment: Is it possible that a familyID exists in tbl_verifier but not in tbl_family? What about different locations? Can tbl_verifier have familyID duplicates?

Comment: **MySQL** as mentioned in the title, or (Microsoft) **SQL Server** as tagged?!?!?!?!

Comment: The main problem here is that you store data in a strange way. Fix that and you will not have this problem.

Comment: @jahlh  familyID exists in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the different answers posted above, i was able to come up with the following script which worked

```
 ; with cte as (select f.familyID,
  f.Members,
  f.Location
  from tbl_family f
  inner join tbl_verifier v ON f.familyID = v.familyID
  and f.Members = v.Members 

  union all

  select f.familyID,
  f.Members,
  f.Location from tbl_family f
  left join tbl_verifier v ON f.familyID = v.familyID 
  where f.Members is NULL
)
SELECT * INTO temp1 FROM cte

SELECT * FROM tbl_family WHERE familyID NOT IN (SELECT familyID FROM temp1)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM temp1
ORDER BY familyID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION All` to merge two result sets

```
    select *
    from tbl_family f
    inner join tbl_verifier v ON f.familyID = v.familyID
    and f.Members = v.Members 

    union all

    select * from tbl_family f
    left join tbl_verifier v ON f.familyID = v.familyID and and f.Members = v.Members
    where v.familyID is null
```

Comment: This is only returning two rows; for familyID 100 and 101. I need 102 and 103 to be included as well

Comment: 102 is still not being returned

Answer (score 0):

how that sounds? I think it works

```
SELECT f.*
FROM tbl_family f, tbl_verifier v
WHERE (f.familyID = v.familyID AND f.Members = v.Members)
      OR f.familyID NOT IN (SELECT familyID FROM tbl_verifier)
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed.

Comment: This is still returning duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL for your case, but it is better to add a location filter for same.

```
; with cte as (
    select tbl_family.family_id, tbl_family.Members, tbl_family.location
    from tbl_family 
    inner join tbl_verifier ON tbl_family.familyID = tbl_verifier.familyID
    and tbl_family.Members = tbl_verifier.Members and tbl_family.Location = tbl_verifier.Location 
    union all
    select tbl_family.family_id, tbl_family.Members, tbl_family.location
    from tbl_family 
    left join tbl_verifier ON tbl_family.familyID = tbl_verifier.familyID 
    where tbl_family.Members is null
)
Select * from cte order by family_id
```

Comment: this is returning 2 rows only. For familyID 100 and 101 without the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` seems like a reasonable solution.  The big question is how to get one row out of the first table if there are multiple rows.

Here is one method that uses `MAX()`:

```
select v.familyID, v.Members, v.Location
from tbl_verifier v
union all
select f.familyID, max(f.Members), f.Location
from tbl_family f
where not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_verifier v
                  where v.familyId = f.familyId
                 );
```

Your question is unclear as to whether families can be in multiple locations.  If so, you need to include `location` in the correlation clause.